# Java - Switching between JPanels with their own JPanels and resizing these inner JPanels and components depending on JFrame size

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I am making program in Java where I have some JPanels with different layouts and I want to switch between them. On these JPanels I have another JPanels with other components (like JButtons and JLabels) and I want to resize them depending on JFrame size (e.g. JPanel on JPanel with height equal to half the size of content pane of JFrame).

I tried to make these JPanels and directly remove or add them to JFrame nad then pack, revalidate and repaint JFrame but sometimes JPanels did not show when I started program.

I also tried using CardLayout. I made JPanels and add them to container added in JFrame. Switching was fine but I cannot resize JPanels and other components on JPanels in CardLayout container because when I tried to get size of content pane of JFrame or size of CardLayout container with JPanels I recived width and height equal to zero.

So, is there any way to achieve this?

I am sorry if I wrote it unintelligibly. Actually I want to make a game with various scenes and when you click on some button it switches to another scene with different components (JPanels, JButtons, images...). Maybe I can use one main JPanel in JFrame and then change its layout and remove and add background image, JPanels, JButtons and so on depending on scene but I dont know if it is possible and if there won't occur another problems.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

CardLayout is able to size its container so that it will fit the largest preferred size of any component that has been added to it, and so this is what you should be using. The problem that you need to solve is the the current component card preferred sizes are not working as you would like them to. The most common reason for this occurrence is due to use of null layouts and absolute positioning, and if you're using this in any of your card component JPanels then don't. Also you may need to override `getPreferredSize()` on any misbehaving card component JPanels if you need more direct control over what the preferred size is. I've often done this if my JPanel displays an image in the paintComponent method, and I want my JPanel to be big enough to do this.

For better help, consider creating and posting your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for your problem.

Comment: I don't use absolute positioning but I only want to specify size of inner components e.g. JPanel on JPanel with height equal to half the size of content pane of JFrame but I can't get real size of frame or its content pane in constructor of JPanel class which is inside CardLayout container.

Comment: (1+) - `JPanel on JPanel with height equal to half the size of content pane of JFrame ` - so the panel you add to the CardLayout could be a panel with a GridLayout. You haven't posted our `SSCCE` so we can't help further.